# Wordpress returns 404 on existing file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following stucture:

Wordpress installed in root, and an `/api/api.php` file manually created

When I go to `www.example.com/api/api.php` I get a 404

This is my `.htaccess` in the root folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^api/api\.php$ - [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I expect this should have let requests to /api/api.php through unmolested.

Also, I tried putting in a .htaccess file in /api with just

```
# disable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine off
```

but I am still getting a 404 error despite this.

The rest of the site works fine, and I have tried disabling all WP plugins just in case.

Comment: I also tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784743/why-is-my-last-rule-l-not-working-in-apache

Comment: Given all that you've tried, it's probably worth turning [RewriteLog[(http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLog) to see what it's actually doing…

Answer (score 0):

try change your permalink from admin panel or if you have an IIS7 server then your permalink should be like %postname%index.php.

and also try this .htaccess code and instead of 'example' write your site base path name

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /example/index.php [L]
```

Comment: The permalinks are working fine. Problem is that I can't access an existing file `/api/api.php` which is throwing a 404 error. Actually the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` statement is not working?

Comment: add   RewriteBase /rest/ after RewriteEngine On

Comment: i think the problem is in your RewriteRule ^api/api\.php$ - [L], so try this statement RewriteRule ^api(/.*)? /api.php [L,R].

Comment: That gives me the WP 404 page when I try to access `/api/api.php` from a browser.